# How to make work together an Ant filelist inside an Ant copy

Tags: ant

I would like to use the result of the following filelist (Ant):

```
<filelist id="docfiles" dir="doc">
    <file name="foo.xml"/>
    <file name="bar.xml"/>
</filelist>
```

into the following copy :

```
<copy todir="folder">
??? 
</copy>
```

I have already tried to put them together like:

```
<copy todir="folder">
 <filelist id="docfiles" dir="doc">
  <file name="foo.xml"/>
  <file name="bar.xml"/>
 </filelist>
</copy>
```

But Ant answer that FileLists is not supported in a such task.
Thanks.

Comment: What version of Ant are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specified in the latest [Ant copy task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) documentation:

> Parameters specified as nested elements
>   `fileset` ***or any other resource collection***
>
> [Resource Collections](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#collection) are used to select groups of files to copy. To use a resource collection, the todir attribute must be set.
>
> **Prior to Ant 1.7 only `<fileset>` has been supported as a nested element.**

Since Resource Collections include:

- fileset, dirset, filelist, and path  (and derivative types) expose file resources
- tarfileset can expose file or tarentry resources depending on configuration
- zipfileset can expose file or zipentry resources depending on configuration
- propertyset exposes property resources

A `filelist` within a `copy` element should work in Ant 1.7.

It will not be supported with Ant 1.6.x.